# Accumulate strings in a list of strings on each iteration

Tags: python, list

How can I add elements from a list to another by actualizing the result through iterations in Python ? I've been struggling for hours.

I mean :

```
li = []
li2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in li2:
    li.append(i)

print(li)

#RESULT i am looking for : ['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD']
```

Thanks!

Comment: li = [''.join(li2[:i+1]) for i in range(len(li2))]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite simply with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate
list(accumulate(li2))
# ['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD']
```

Which by default has `func=operator.add` as function argument:

> def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add, *, initial=None):

So it will add the previous values to the current on each successive iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the following way:

```
li = []
li2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

string = ''
for i in li2:
  string +=i
  li.append(string)

print(li)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = []
li2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for index,i in enumerate(li2):
      li.append(''.join(li2[:index])+i)
```

Explanation: using enumerate(), you can loop over a list with its index. Now, ''.join() helps us to add any list element as a string.