# Python adding subsequent list members to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a following list of elements:

```
['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
```

and I would like to end up with:

```
['e1', 'e1e2', 'e1e2e3']
```

Currently I have the following code that achieves it, but I would like to know whether is there any other method, like a list comprehension, that would make the solution shorter. I'm open to all suggestions, including crazy ones. Also it doesn't need to be a list but anything iterable.

```
my_list = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
new_list = []
add_elem = ''
for elem in my_list:
    add_elem += elem
    new_list.append(add_elem)
```

Comment: Your current code looks quite suitable.

Comment: Thank you. As a learning exercise I'm looking for ways to compact it.

Comment: OK. But if someone suggests something shorter but less clear, don't take it as an improvement.

Comment: Also: [Accumulate strings in a list of strings on each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61917350/7851470) and [Adding strings, first, first + second, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63630408/7851470)

Comment: Yes, accumulating is what I've been searching for and it's been suggested in the answers already. Also list comprehension example given was also great, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
import itertools

lst = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
print(list(itertools.accumulate(lst)))
```

More usage are described in docs

Comment: This is short and sweet, I didn't think of looking at itertools, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list comprehension.

```py
my_list = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
new_list = [''.join(my_list[0:x+1]) for x in range(len(my_list))]
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out but I couldn't. This is something I need to go over a bit to understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter code doesn't mean it's better, readability is the most important factor. That said, you could use `str.join` and `slices`:

```
my_list, new_list = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'], []
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    new_list.append(''.join(my_list[:i+1]))
```

But really, your solution is just as good.